# Disable COD if subtotal is greater then xxxx amount

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

How can I disable the **Cash on delivery** option on checkout page, if the order **subtotal** is greater then a specific amount ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to **System > configuration > Sales > Payment methods** > select **Cash on delivery**.

you can see "**Minimum order total**" field, just enter **xxxx** , it will not allow to checkout if the amount is greater than `xxxx`

[image]

Comment: Oh good ans :) :)

Comment: Yes it is good answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
System > configuration >  Payment methods > Cash on delivery.
```

Set 'minimum or maximum order total' value. COD will not allow to checkout if order amount will be less than added value.